# WPF Caliburn IViewFactory does not find Constructor - 'Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DependencyResolverException'

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, caliburn.micro

I am working on WPF application (.NET 4.5) that is using MVVM and `Caliburn` to bootstrap Views by using `IViewFactory` interface.
I ran into peculiar issue where all but one (`QuestionRadioBtnViewModel`) of my ViewModels are getting initialised.
On runtime when I am trying to initialize viewModel

```
var questionRadBtnVm = _viewFactory.CreateQuestionRadioBtnViewModel(answer.Text);
```

Error message comes back:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DependencyResolverException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll

Additional information: Could not resolve non-optional dependency for 'Corp.Conveyancing.Desktop.ViewModels.Question.QuestionRadioBtnViewModel' (Corp.Conveyancing.Desktop.ViewModels.Question.QuestionRadioBtnViewModel). Parameter 'stringValue' type 'System.String'
```

However method signature matches constructor just fine.

IViewFactory:

```
 public interface IViewFactory
 {
     QuestionRadioBtnViewModel CreateQuestionRadioBtnViewModel(string textValue);
 }
```

QuestionRadioBtnViewModel

```
 public QuestionRadioBtnViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, string stringValue)
 {
    _stringValue = stringValue;
    _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
 }
```

Caliburn Bootstraper

```
public class ReactiveBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    public ReactiveBootstrapper()
    {
        Log.Info("Starting bootstrapper");
        Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor(typeof(MainViewModel));
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        Container.BuildUp(instance);
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Container = new ApplicationContainer();

        Container.RegisterViewModels(typeof(MainViewModel));

        SetXamlLanguage();
        Container.Install(FromAssembly.Containing<IObjectModelFactory>());
        Container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name + ".exe.log4net"));
        Container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        Container.Register(Component.For<IViewFactory>().AsFactory());
        Container.Register(Component.For<IServerOperations>().ImplementedBy<ServerOperations>());
        Container.Register(Component.For<IQuestionControlFactory>().ImplementedBy<QuestionControlFactory>());
        Container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>(f => f.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero);

        RegisterWcfServices();

        Container.Register(Component.For<IQasManager>().ImplementedBy<QasWebManager>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("url", Settings.Default.QasUrl)));
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return Container.ResolveAll(service).Cast<object>();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
    {
        return new[] {
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
            typeof(MainViewModel).Assembly,
            typeof(MessageViewModel).Assembly
        };
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
        {
            return Container.Resolve(service);
        }
        return Container.Resolve(key, service);
    }
}
```

All the other constructors that are using `IViewFactory` work fine and data is being passed no problem.
I must be missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself.
 It turns out not only the signature of method has to match, but also names of the parameters being passed

```
public QuestionRadioBtnViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, string stringValue)
```

`stringValue` text has to match.

```
public interface IViewFactory
 {
     QuestionRadioBtnViewModel CreateQuestionRadioBtnViewModel(string stringValue);
 }
```